# Laravel pagination with Json resource return error

Tags: json, laravel, pagination, resources

I   have  this  json response.  In  **data** section i need to   get only **uID**  and  **email** only. I  try it  with JsonResource  but  it give me a  error.

**This  is  json  respond  without  JsonResource**

```
{
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "uID": 1,
                "name": "supun",
                "email": "supun@gmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "dob": null,
                "contactNo": null,
                "fbID": null,
                "googleID": null,
                "bloodGroup": null,
                "height": null,
                "weight": null,
                "lID": 1,
                "sID": 1,
                "created_at": "2018-10-24 02:41:47",
                "updated_at": "2018-10-24 02:41:47",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "uID": 4,
                "name": "supun",
                "email": "supun1@gmail.com",
                "email_verified_at": null,
                "dob": null,
                "contactNo": null,
                "fbID": null,
                "googleID": null,
                "bloodGroup": null,
                "height": null,
                "weight": null,
                "lID": 1,
                "sID": 1,
                "created_at": "2018-10-24 02:52:17",
                "updated_at": "2018-10-24 02:52:17",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=3",
        "next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=2",
        "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users",
        "per_page": 2,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 5
    }
```

This  is  the respond  i need to create using jsonresource

```
{
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "uID": 1,
                 "email": "supun@gmail.com"

            },
            {
                "uID": 4,
                "email": "supun1@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=3",
        "next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=2",
        "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users",
        "per_page": 2,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 5
    }
```

This  is  my user **UserController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use  App\Http\Resources\Users as GetAllUsersResource;
    use Validator;
    class UserController extends Controller {


        public function usersApi( Request $request ) {

            $userInfo = User::paginate(2);


            $output = new  GetAllUsersResource($userInfo);

            return response()->json($output, $this->successStatus);




            // return response()->json(['status'  => true,
            //                           'message' => 'done',
            //                          'data'    => $output
            // ], $this->successStatus);
        }


    }
```

and  this is my  **JsonResource**

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
class Users extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
    //return parent::toArray($request->data);
        return [
       'uID' =>$this->uID,
         'email' =>$this->email,
          ];
    }
}
```

This  is the error  i got after add it  to  JsonResource

```
 "message": "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Pagination\\LengthAwarePaginator::$uID",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myworks\\pharmeasylk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Resources\\DelegatesToResource.php",
    "line": 120,
```

I  try many  other  ways  but  no  luck.  this work only  for if user return  only  one  row.  but  pagination  contain   many user data and links data . If some  can  help me  with it. big help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're giving the collection to an `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` class (which expects to receive a single object) instead of giving it to a `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection` class, which expects to receive a collection.

From the docs:

> In addition to generating resources that transform individual models,
>   you may generate resources that are responsible for transforming
>   collections of models. This allows your response to include links and
>   other meta information that is relevant to an entire collection of a
>   given resource.
>
> To create a resource collection, you should use the --collection flag
>   when creating the resource. Or, including the word Collection in the
>   resource name will indicate to Laravel that it should create a
>   collection resource. Collection resources extend the 
>   Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection class:
>
> php artisan make:resource Users --collection
>
> php artisan make:resource UserCollection
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#generating-resources

If you're not doing anything fancy to transform your collection, this might also work without changing your JsonResource class:

```
$output = GetAllUsersResource::collection($userInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

what does the `__construct()` method do in the `GetAllUsersResource` class

```
$output = new  GetAllUsersResource($userInfo);
```

you might wanted to do this instead !?

```
  $output = new  GetAllUsersResource($userInfo->items());
```

Comment: Good  Sir  I done  as  you  mention  but  i get this error  `Cannot access protected property Illuminate\\Pagination\\LengthAwarePaginator::$items` . I'm new to  Laravel .can you bit explain to me.

Comment: sorry, access it as a method `items()`. it will return an array with the users in it

Comment: But Sir  i  need  other data also  like (`last_page, per_page , total`)    after add  `$output = new  GetAllUsersResource($userInfo->items());` it  give me this error  `Trying to get property 'uID' of non-object`

Comment: post in your question the class `GetAllUserResource`